# Jupyter on NERSC with Tensorflow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

It's great that NERSC has this direct link to Jupyter Notebook by going to https://ipython.nersc.gov/

Also they have Tensorflow built-in into their Cori system, which you simply activate the corresponding Python module first using:

```
$ module load python
$ source activate deeplearning
```

And then you can use

```
$ python
>> import tensorflow as tf
```

However, these two don't seem to share a connection. What I'm trying to do is to import tensorflow in the jupyter notebook from the web link.

Has anyone done similar things on Edison/Cori yet? Your guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baiyu,

Sorry for the late response. You may have already seen this, but
the documentation has changed since you posted this: http://www.nersc.gov/users/data-analytics/data-analytics/deep-learning/

Check out the notebooks section. The gist of the docs is:

1. Remember to do `module load deeplearning` instead of `source activate deeplearning`
2. As long as you have done `module load deeplearning` at least once on Cori, the deeplearning kernel should be copied to your home directory and you should be able to use it at ipython.nersc.gov

Tensorflow does not yet work on ipython.nersc.gov due to some library issues, but the other frameworks will work (Theano, scikit-learn, Keras, Lasagne, etc.).

Once ipython.nersc.gov gets pointed at Cori, you should be able to use Tensorflow there

Also, to ensure a much quicker response from me or anyone else at NERSC, you should check https://my.nersc.gov/tickets.php and file a ticket.